# Campo de variable OLD en trigger AFTER DELETE se queda nulo Postgres

Tags: postgresql, trigger

tengo este trigger en Postgres el cual comienza con este código:

```
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    SELECT id,id_capsules,id_organizations INTO rec_user FROM security.users WHERE id = NEW.creator;        
  ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
    SELECT id,id_capsules,id_organizations INTO rec_user FROM security.users WHERE id = NEW.modifier; 
  ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN    
    SELECT id,id_capsules,id_organizations INTO rec_user FROM security.users WHERE id = OLD.modifier; 
  END IF;
```

La ejecución me da error se dispara en el AFTER DELETE, detecté que el problema está en que la variable OLD.modifier al parecer no tiene valor, se queda nula. Es posible que eso pase, que esta variable se quede vacía en el AFTER DELETE?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Podrías por favor, poner el mensaje completo de error en tu pregunta? Recuerda que puedes editarla todas las veces que necesites usando el enlace bajo las etiquetas

Comment: Hola, en la misma funcion que ejecuta el trigger, más abajo se realizan varios INSERT (es una funcion para guardar trazas) pero ese INSERT depende del valor obtenido en la consulta mostrada, al estar vacía o nula la variable OLD, esa consulta no devuelve nada y hace que falle el INSERT, probé a clavar en el código el ID que debe devolver y funcionó. Es como si por alguna razón la variable OLD estuviera vacía.

Comment: Haz tu ejemplo mínimo más completo. El problema puede ser otro.